# Finding the last element in cumsum

Tags: arrays, matlab

I would to use cumsum to find the sum up to 5 for example, but I want the end not all the intermediate values.

For example:

```
A = [1:5];
B = cumsum(A)
```

returns

```
B =

     1     3     6    10    15
```

I just want 15 not the rest.

What I have tried:

`B = cumsum(A)(end)` but it gives me this error:

```
??? Error: ()-indexing must appear last in an index expression.
```

Comment: you can try `sum(1:5)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last element of cumsum is per definition equal to the sum. Hence you just need:

```
A = [1:5];
B = sum(A)
```

Of course you can also do what you tried to do, with a detour:

```
A = [1:5];
B = cumsum(A);
B(end)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
C = B(length(A))
```

or

```
C = B(end)
```

or all in one line

```
C = sum(A)
```

All these will give you

```
C =

    15
```

Comment: In that case `B(end)` should be better.